# Take mean of a subset of rows selected using a boolean vector produced for each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I can do the following using sapply, but I wanted if dplyr can do it as well, or if it's a problem outside the scope of dplyr.

I have three columns, one with dates (Date), one with date intervals (Intervals), and the third with numeric values (Values).

What I want to do is for each row:

1) Get the value Date

2) See inside which intervals Date is present (Date %within% Intervals), and produce the corresponding boolean vector

3) Use this boolean vector to subset the entire original dataframe

4) Take the mean of the Values for this dataframe

5) Store the value in a new column called mean_for_Date

For the following input the values for the column mean_for_Date would be 3 and 1:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame( Date = as.Date(c("1998-01-02", "1998-01-06")), Values =  c(1, 3))
df$Intervals <- c(interval(df[2, "Date"] - days(2), df[2, "Date"] + days(2)), interval(df[1, "Date"] - days(2), df[1, "Date"] + days(2)))
```

In sapply I did it like this:

```
df$mean_for_Date <- sapply(df$Date, function (x) mean(df$Values[x %within% df$Intervals], na.rm = T))
```

Thanks in advance for all possible advice

Comment: can you provide your sapply solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::mutate` and `purrr::map_dbl` in the `tidyverse` can do the same

```r
library(lubridate) # date
library(magrittr)  # %>% and %<>%
library(tidyverse) # mutate and map_dbl

df <- data.frame( Date = as.Date(c("1998-01-02", "1998-01-06")), Values =  c(1, 3))
df$Intervals <- c(interval(df[2, "Date"] - days(2), df[2, "Date"] + days(2)), 
                  interval(df[1, "Date"] - days(2), df[1, "Date"] + days(2))) 

df %<>%
  mutate(mean_for_Date = map_dbl(Date, ~ mean(Values[. %within% Intervals], na.rm = TRUE)))
df

#>         Date Values                      Intervals mean_for_Date
#> 1 1998-01-02      1 1998-01-04 UTC--1998-01-08 UTC             3
#> 2 1998-01-06      3 1997-12-31 UTC--1998-01-04 UTC             1

str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ Date         : Date, format: "1998-01-02" "1998-01-06"
#>  $ Values       : num  1 3
#>  $ Intervals    :Formal class 'Interval' [package "lubridate"] with 3 slots
#>   .. ..@ .Data: num  345600 345600
#>   .. ..@ start: POSIXct, format: "1998-01-04" ...
#>   .. ..@ tzone: chr "UTC"
#>  $ mean_for_Date: num  3 1
```

Created on 2018-03-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be achieved by using a `dummy` column to apply `cartesian join` between each row of data frame `df` to self-join it with itsefl.

I have taken away few not required columns while preparing to join. The cartesian join provides all possible combinations of  `Date` and `Intervals`. I have kept the `Values` along with `Interval` so that when `Date` is matched then corresponding `Values` can be taken.

`IsFound` decides the rows in which `Date` is `within` Intervals. We need to `filter` only those rows with `IsFound` true because `Values` from those will derive `mean` for that date.

The solution will work if a `Date` is found within multiple `Interval`. The `group_by` will finally help to find `mean`.

```
  library(dplyr)
  df %>% select(-Values, - Intervals) %>% mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
    inner_join(select(df, -Date) %>% mutate(dummy = 1), by="dummy") %>%
    mutate(IsFound = Date %within% Intervals) %>%
    filter(IsFound) %>%
    select(-dummy, - IsFound) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(Values))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Date        Mean
#  <date>     <dbl>
#1 1998-01-02  3.00
#2 1998-01-06  1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm seeing the problem too simplistically? Would this get the mean(as a function of date) given the dates fall in the interval?

```
 df <- df %>% 
          left_join(df %>% 
                       filter(Date %within% Intervals & !is.na(Values)) %>% 
                       group_by(Date) %>% 
                       summarise(mean_for_Date = mean(Values)) %>% 
                       select(Date,mean_for_Date)), by="Date")
```

Comment: Does above solution produces result as expected by `OP`? Can you please check at your end?